# PLS-00201: identifier must be declared in ORACLE TRIGGER

Tags: oracle11g

I have this set of data. I want to develop a trigger which fires when rows with ICICUT = IB are updated. So far it's proving a challenge because of error "PLS-00201: identifier 'OLD.ICICUT' must be declared". What am I missing?

```
ICICUT    ICICU          ICAME  
IB        11368          65625         
V         711340         63808       
V         711313         24812    
IB        711265         60238        
O         711322         21570   
RB        711370         348590
```

my trigger....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EOGONY.F0011_audit
BEFORE UPDATE
ON INVOICES 
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.ICICUT = 'IB')
ENABLE
DECLARE
    v_date  varchar2(30);
BEGIN
   SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO v_date from dual;
    INSERT INTO AUDIT_HISTORY_F0011 (ICICUT, ICICU, ICUSER, ICDICJ, OLD_ICAME, NEW_ICAME, ENTRY_DATE, OPERATION) 
    VALUES (:OLD.ICICUT, :OLD.ICICU , :NEW.ICUSER, :OLD.ICDICJ, :OLD.ICAME, :NEW.ICAME, v_date, 'Updating');
END;
```

Comment: @AnkitBajpai tried your solution but got ORA-25000: invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile code without errors after applying these changes...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EOGONY.F0011_audit
BEFORE UPDATE
ON INVOICES 
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
    v_date  varchar2(30);

BEGIN
   IF ( :OLD.ICICUT = 'IB' ) THEN
   SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO v_date from dual;

    INSERT INTO AUDIT_HISTORY_F0011 (ICICUT, ICICU, ICUSER, ICDICJ, OLD_ICAME, NEW_ICAME, ENTRY_DATE, OPERATION) 
    VALUES (:OLD.ICICUT, :OLD.ICICU , :NEW.ICUSER, :OLD.ICDICJ, :OLD.ICAME, :NEW.ICAME, v_date, 'Updating');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reason, but after my test, :NEW or :OLD parameter sometime cannot be used in DML, you need to declare local variable ( eg. v_ICICT) and assign NEW / OLD parameter to them, and use local variables in insert script, the compile will be ok. you can try it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).